# installing windows 7 iso in virtual pc

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I am trying to install windows 7 iso on my windows 7 host machine. i am mounting it on virtual cd/dvd drive and it boots into setup just fine.

however, i get a load driver message that i've no clue what to do?

[image]

Comment: You should try Oracle VirtualBox. I've had much better luck with it.

Comment: What settings did you use on the Virtual PC?

Comment: I just set the DVD to look at iso and i think that was it.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing wrong with your ISO? that looks like missing drivers on the CD. Is this ISO from a OEM cd?

Comment: Trial enterprise from MS site.